# how to convert result of LISTAGG function to corresponding java model type in Hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am fetching a list of objects from oracle db. One of the fields is a collection of IDs (childrenIds) and I am using LISTAGG function in my SQL to return a comma separated list for that field. I want hibernate to convert that list (which is a String) to List of longs. Is there any way to do that in Hibernate? I am using addScalar method for non-collection fields but I don't know how to do it for a comma separated list.

Comment: I'm not a Java developer, but isn't it common practice to add the child object to your mappings and have Hibernate fetch all children by itself? It sounds like extra work to have the database `listagg` it and Hibernate to split it again.